# webRTC multi-peer connection Flutter

Tags: flutter, webrtc, webrtc-android

I want to establish a peer connection between multiple users using WebRTC in Flutter for a data channel. I am encountering an error while attempting to create multiple connections. For example, if I have three users named A, B, and C, sometimes A can connect to B, but when B tries to connect to C, it disconnects from A.

Please help me if anyone has the code or any suggestions on how I can create multiple peer connections between users.

My requirements are as follows:

- If A sends something through the data channel, both B and C should receive it.
- If B sends something through the data channel, both A and C should receive it.
- If C sends something through the data channel, both A and B should receive it.